# Python web-scraping trouble

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I've been with this all day and I'm getting a little overwhelmed, I explain, I have a personal project, scrape all the links of the acestream: // protocol from a website and turn them into a playlist for acestream. For now I can either remove the links from the web (something like the site map) or remove the acestream links from a specific subpage. One of the problems I have is that since the same acestream link appears several times on the page,
Obviously I get the same link multiple times and I only want it once. Besides, I don't know how to do it either (I'm very new to this) so that instead of putting the link in it, it automatically takes it from a list of links in a .csv, because I need to get an acestream link from each link that I put on it. in the .csv. I'm sorry about the tirade, I hope it's not a nuisance.
Hope you understand, I translated it with Google Translate

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# creating empty list
urls = []

# function created
def scrape(site):
    # getting the request from url
    r = requests.get(site)
    
    # converting the text
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    for i in s.find_all("a"):
        href = i.attrs['href']
        if href.startswith("acestream://"):
            site = site + href
            if site not in urls:
                urls.append(site)
                print(site)
                # calling the scrape function itself
                # generally called recursion
                scrape(site)
                
# main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    site = "https://www.websitehere.com/index.htm"
    scrape(site)
```

Comment: Is the .csv relevant to the question? I don't see any .csv IO references in the code you provided. It looks like you're trying to get all the links that aren't related to the `site` you're requesting, is that true?

Comment: You don't see how I call the csv because I don't know how to do it.
The .csv contains approximately 200 links to scrap the "acvestream://" links

Comment: is the .csv on your computer? What are the steps you want to do? 1. read csv from ________ that contains URLs 2. using the URLs, do ________

Comment: 1. Read .csv (or txt whatever) from where I'am (./), the file contains a column with 200 links in each row. 2. Scrap each URL to get one acestream:// link from each link in my .csv or .txt or whatever. 3. I export each result acestream:// link to a result.txt file, next step is make a playlist with that info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Based off your last comment and your code, you can read in a .csv using

```py
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'C:\<path to your csv>'

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
csv_links = df['<your_column_name_for_links>'].to_list()
```

With this, you can get the URLs from the .csv. Just change the values in the `<>`.